# Swiftui change tabview bar color

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

Here is my view:

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        CountriesView(homeViewModel: homeViewModel)
            .tabItem {
                Label {
                    Text("Home")
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                homeViewModel.getCountries()
            }

        SavedCountriesView(homeViewModel: homeViewModel)
            .tabItem {
                Label {
                    Text("Saved")
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                }
            }
    }
    .onAppear {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(Color.black)
    }
}
```

I have managed to change background and unselectedItem color but I can't change the color when item selected.

[image]

Here is what I've tried so far:

1-) Change UITabBar's barTintColor property.

2- Change the text and the image color from their properties. Adding foreground color to them does not effect this.

3-) Change TabView's accent color even tho it's deprecated on future versions. Also changing the accent color effects the whole page. I just want to change selected item colors.

Answer (score 0):

`TabView` seems to use your Apps AccentColor for the selected color. So you can either define it in your Asset Catalog or manually set it for the `TabView` like this

```swift
TabView {

}
.accentColor(.red)
```

`.accentColor` seems to be soft-deprecated though and to be replaced with `.tint` in the future, but unlike `.accentColor` the `.tint` modifier does not seem to be honored.

Comment: The problem is using accentColor makes the whole ui using the same color. When I use accent color tabview item colors change but also the back button color changes when navigate to another page

Answer (score 0):

Using this in .onAppear worked for me:

```
.onAppear() {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .systemPink
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = .black
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor:  UIColor.black]
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor:  UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)]
    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```